# How to pass currency to payment geteway in USD only

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using wordpress + WMPL + WPML Multilangual with default wocommerce currency is USD, Product currency are shown based on visitors location i.e Egypt = EGP, Saudi Arabia = SAR, other countries = USD

i am using a payment gateway called vapulus which accept payment only in one currency such as USD

so i need to convert any currencies to USD when passing payment to vapulus gateway

Comment: There is a simple rule called, 'do not solve until broken'. Question is, are you facing different currency on that payment gateway module for different region/language?

Comment: sorry if i can't understand well,  the problem when user show the product in different currency rather than the default in USD, i.e if user in saudi arabia the price will be in SAR currency, so when he go to checkout the price still shown in SAR, so when he choose the payment getway vapulus and click confirm, he will transfered to vapulus webpage that show different ammount than in the checkout page because vapulus only accept USD